# How could one measure the accuracy of various data sources

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, modeling, inference

I have a dataset of websites' total entries, broken down by website. This set contains the ground truth data, as well as estimation of the same data from multiple service providers. I would like to find some sort of measure (or preferably, multiple measures) that will provide a score on the estimation performance of each provider.

One easy check is to measure the deviation (absolute value or squared error) from the ground truth for each data point. Then I can look at the mean and variance of the deviation, as well as the distribution of it (I believe a normal distribution is a healthy sign).

However I would like to develop additional, more interesting, measures, and honestly I don't have many ideas. Could anyone offer such measures? Any ideas to start with?

Comment: You'd have to begin with a clear criterion for what you mean by a 'close' estimate. Unbiasedness $[E(T)=\tau],$ minimum variance among unbiased estimators, minimum MSE $=E[(T-\tau)^2],$ and many others have been proposed. // Different criteria will lead to (perhaps surprisingly) different assessments.

Comment: @BruceET I'm looking for additional ways to define "close". What other ways, except for MSE are you aware of?

Comment: Where $T$ is estimator and $\tau$ is parameter being estimated: _Mean absolute deviation_ $E[|T- \tau|]$ is another.